# 'Exception: Action not allowed' when attempting to programmatically add an Installable Trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I have a template google sheet that our company duplicates for every project.
The final result I want is to have an onEdit trigger that does a POST request. I actually already have this working. The issue stems from this: This trigger cannot be a simple trigger, it must be an installable trigger because according to Google's restrictions, simple triggers cannot make external requests, but installable triggers can. Again, all of that works, I just have to set up the installable trigger manually.
As I mentioned, this is a template document, so creating a new installable trigger manually every time it is duplicated is a real pain. I want to improve my UX by having it done automatically. Now the API documentation DOES detail how you can do this programmatically [right here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically). So it definitely should be possible if I'm reading this correctly.

In order to have this trigger automatically created, I, of course, must use another trigger. In this case, it MUST be a simple trigger or we're back with the same issue.

So I added this onOpen() simple trigger function to my code: (convertAlias is the name of the function to run when the onEdit trigger activates)

```js
function onOpen() {
  if (ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('convertAlias')
      .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetId())
      .onEdit()
      .create()
  }
}
```

When I open the document though, I get no results. The stack logging shows the error as `Exception: Action not allowed.` The error specifically originates from the create() call.

I thought that maybe there was some issue with creating an installable trigger from a simple trigger so I went for the next best thing, a button. I added a button to my spreadsheet that was linked to the same code as a "generateTrigger()" function. Pushing that actually DID bring up the Authorization screen, which is what is expected. But then after authorizing my account, it then goes on to report the same `Exception: Action not allowed.` After that initial authorization, it does not ask me again and automatically goes to that error. I get the same results from running the function manually in the editor.

Is there any way I can make this installable trigger happen with any sort of automation? Is this an issue with my code, a permissions issue, or something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears I should have just been passing the sheet and not the ID? Doesn't seem right but getting rid of getSheetId() made it work!

Comment: That's correct - see [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically).